# Java - String parsed from Java.Util.Scanner includes unwanted whitespace in front

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to store two variables from user input, one a char that's at the very beginning of input, the second a string that in the input follows the char. For my set of data sets there will always be a char at front and a string following after, separated by a whitespace, for example:

```
n It's a sunny day
n Nobody
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      char charToSearch;
      String inputString;
      
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      charToSearch = scnr.next().charAt(0);
      inputString = scnr.nextLine();
      
      System.out.println(charToSearch);
      System.out.println(inputString);
      
   }
}
```

For the input 'z Today is Monday', I'm getting the result

```
z
 Today is monday
```

I expected:

```
z
Today is Monday
```

As you can see there's a whitespace in front of the actual input. I want the string to contain no whitespace in front.

I assumed that the issue is something with the buffer (something I frankly do not understand well enough), so I tried to 'clear' the buffer and consume the whitespace by using `scnr.next()`, like this:

```
charToSearch = scnr.next().charAt(0);
scnr.next();
inputString = scnr.nextLine();
```

But that only leads to the string getting cut off, like this:

```
z
 is Monday
```

I am using online IDE, if that is relevant here.

Comment: String has a `trim()` method to remove leading/trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `trim()` function on the string. Simply use `inputString.trim()` function to clear the whitespace around the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`Scanner#skip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#skip-java.lang.String-) to go past the whitespace.

```
scnr.skip("\\s+");
```

You could also use [`String#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) to remove leading whitespace.

```
inputString = scnr.nextLine().replaceAll("^\\s+", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify it and read the entire line and then parse it with your logic. Like,

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  
String line = scnr.nextLine();
char charToSearch = line.charAt(0);
String inputString = line.substring(2);
  
System.out.println(charToSearch);
System.out.println(inputString);
```